# ./server_start.sh: line 41: kill: (21556) - No such process

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I was trying to start the jobserver.It fails and i dont see any logs for ERROR

/usr/share/dse/spark/spark-jobserver
./server_start.sh: line 41: kill: (21556) - No such process

Comment: and what the commands inside that `.sh` file? it is not releated to job you want to start, it is related to something inside the sh file!

Answer (score 1):

You need to start it with the `dse` command

```
dse spark-jobserver start [any_spark_submit_options] //Start the job server
dse spark-jobserver stop  //Stop the job server
```

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJobserverOverview.html

If that doesn't fix it it probably means a false start or improper shutdown has left a `spark-jobserver.pid` file in the spark-jobserver resource dir. Remove this so that the following code can pass.

```
if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ] && kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
   echo 'Job server is already running'
   exit 1
fi
```

This code is checking to see if that PID file exists and if it does it tries to get info from the process. If the process doesn't exist then that means the pid file is there in error and must be removed (or you lack permission).

Comment: I'm trying to start with dse spark-jobserver start
/usr/share/dse/spark/spark-jobserver
/usr/share/dse/spark/spark-jobserver/server_start.sh: line 41: kill: (28083) - No such process

Comment: Just "dse spark-jobserver start" like I said

Comment: Means you have an old PID file in that dir probably

Comment: If that didn't make sense, you need to remove the `spark-jobserver.pid` file if one is still sitting in that directory.